# Extracting a tar file from a .tgz file

Tags: go

i have some issue with the package archive/tar.
Using the `tarReader.Next()` he recognize a file that should be considered as a file as a directory. The issue with that  is the fact that it's a .tar file in it and i need it as a file to process it as well.

The fragment of code that recognize the file

```
        header, err := tarReader.Next()
        fmt.Println(header.Typeflag)
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }

        name := header.Name
        fmt.Println(name)
```

Files:

```
file.tgz
-file.tar
--other files
```

Here is the full function

```
 package main

import (
    "archive/tar"
    "compress/gzip"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    // get the arguments from the command line
    flag.Int("n", 4, "an integer")
    flag.Parse()

    sourceFile := flag.Arg(0)

    if sourceFile == "" {
        fmt.Println("Dude, you didn't pass in a tar file!")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    fmt.Println("arg 1: ", flag.Arg(0))

    processFile(sourceFile)
}

// ReadPackedFile is a function to unpack a tar.gz
func ReadPackedFile(filepath string) {
    if filepath == "" {
        panic("Empty input!")
    }

    processFile(filepath)
}

func processFile(srcFile string) {

    f, err := os.Open(srcFile)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    gzf, err := gzip.NewReader(f)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    tarReader := tar.NewReader(gzf)
    // defer io.Copy(os.Stdout, tarReader)

    for true {
        header, err := tarReader.Next()
        fmt.Println(header.Typeflag)
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }

        name := header.Name
        fmt.Println(name)

        switch header.Typeflag {
        case tar.TypeDir: // = directory
            fmt.Println("Directory:", name)
            os.Mkdir(name, 0755)
        case tar.TypeReg: // = regular file
            fmt.Println("Regular file:", name)
            data := make([]byte, header.Size)

            _, err := tarReader.Read(data)

            if err != nil {
                panic("Error reading file!!! PANIC!!!!!!")
            }

            ioutil.WriteFile(name, data, 0755)
        default:
            fmt.Printf("%s : %c %s %s\n",
                "Yikes! Unable to figure out type",
                header.Typeflag,
                "in file",
                name,
            )
        }
    }
}
```

The error given by the console

```
PS C:\Users\ErikT\Workspace\Misc\pen\htmltag> go run .\main.go .\dragontail-12.14.1.tgz
arg 1:  .\dragontail-12.14.1.tgz
53
/
Directory: /
53
12.14.1/
Directory: 12.14.1/
53
12.14.1/css/
Directory: 12.14.1/css/
48
12.14.1/css/view.css
Regular file: 12.14.1/css/view.css
panic: Error reading file!!! PANIC!!!!!!

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.processFile({0xc000014108?, 0xc000006018?})
        C:/Users/ErikT/Workspace/Misc/pen/htmltag/main.go:83 +0x60c
main.main()
        C:/Users/ErikT/Workspace/Misc/pen/htmltag/main.go:27 +0x1a7
exit status 2
```

Comment: I do not understand the question. `archve/tar` cannot read `.tgz` files because a `.tgz` file is a `gzip`-ped TAR stream.

Comment: I mean, if you were to attempt to read a `.tgz` file using the code snippet from the question, I would expect it to fail at the first call to `Next()`.

Comment: Just Posted the full code

Comment: So do I undretstand correctly that your TAR stream contains a file which is itself a TAR archive, but `archive/tar` says it's a directory entry (and you would expect it to be a file entry)? Also: when you run `gunzip -c your_tar.gz | tar -t -v -f -`, does it report an included TAR file as a file? IoW, have you verified using the `tar` program that the stream indeed has expected contents?

Comment: it doesn't report having a tar file in it. But when i want to export it with 7zip there is a tar file in it that i have to export as well. And when i just skip the error given by the code the file are unreadable. I think it's because they are compressed two time

Comment: I updated the question with the full code and the error given by the console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247063/discussion-between-kostix-and-erik-tellier).

Comment: Well, as it turned out in the chat, there was really no issue; the file was a simple `.tar.gz` file with nothing but directories and plain files. A simple implementation written in Go has managed to extract all the stuff just fine, so it appears the problem stated in the question did not really exist.